# Puppeteer Get all data attribute values

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, webautomation

My html doc is

```
<div class="inner-column">
 <div data-thing="abc1"></div>
 <div data-thing="abc2"></div>
 <div data-thing="abc3"></div>
</div>
```

How can I get all "data-thing" value (eg. ["abc1", "abc2", "abc3"]) inside div with class .inner-column?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport({width: 1440, height: 1200})
  await page.goto('https://www.example.com')

  const data = await page.content();

  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [page.$$eval](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args) function for that like this:

```js
const dataValues = await page.$$eval(
    '.inner-column div',
    divs => divs.map(div => div.dataset.thing)
);
```

#### Explanation

What the `page.$$eval` function does (quote from the docs linked above):

> This method runs `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector))` within the page and passes it as the first argument to `pageFunction`.
>
> If `pageFunction` returns a Promise, then `page.$$eval` would wait for the promise to resolve and return its value.

Therefore, it will first query the targeted divs and then map the divs to their `data-*` value by using the [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access) property.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `evaluate` function

```js
const data = await page.evaluate(() => 
  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".inner-column DIV")).map(d => d.getAttribute("data-thing"))
)
```