# Get dataset object from an element in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

Say i have this element:

```
<a href="#" class="employee"
  data-id="123"
  data-name="john doe"
>
```

I'd like to get the data attributes via dataset.
I can use the code below to get an individual data attribute,
but if i want to get both data-* attributes, i'd have to scrape twice.

```
const person = await page.$eval(".employee", (el) =>
  el.getAttribute("data-id")
);
```

I've tried this, but returns an empty object

```
const person = await page.$eval(".employee", (el) =>
  el.dataset
);
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55797082/puppeteer-get-all-data-attribute-values

Comment: @dikuw almost but not quite, because it returns an array of the values. I'm looking to get an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to accomplish it with this, but still very open to know how to retrieve the dataset object.

```
const dataset = await page.$eval(".employee", (el) => {
   return {
      id: el.getAttribute("data-id"),
      name: el.getAttribute("data-name")
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `el.attributes` which will return all the attributes of the element and then you can get the data from the returned value without having to scrape twice.

Or in general try saving the element and then getting the data from it,
or use regex to select the attributes that starts with `data-`

Comment: No luck. I get back `{ '0': {}, '1': {}, '2': {}, '3': {}, '4': {}, '5': {}, '6': {} }`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const html = `
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'><title>Test</title></head>
    <body>
      <a href='#' class='employee' data-id='123' data-name='john doe'>John Doe</a>
    </body>
  </html>`;

try {
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto(`data:text/html,${encodeURIComponent(html)}`);

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const dataset = document.querySelector('a').dataset;
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(dataset));
  });
  console.log(data); // { id: '123', name: 'john doe' }
} catch (err) { console.error(err); } finally { await browser.close(); }
```